# spans inside div running off page

Tags: css

I've seen some posts about this issue, but nothing's working for me right now. I have a div inside of which are many spans. The spans are running off the page. Can anyone help me please wrap the spans to keep them on the page?

HTML:

```
    <div id="creditsbar">
<span class="title">Writing</span> <span class="name">Bob, Mary</span> 
<span class="smallsquare">&#9632;</span> 
<span class="title">Editing</span> 
<span class="name">Mary, Bob</span> 
<span class="smallsquare">&#9632;</span> 
<span class="title">Design</span> 
<span class="name">Bob</span> 
<span class="smallsquare">&#9632;</span> 
<span class="title">Development</span> 
<span class="name">Mary</span> 
<span class="smallsquare">&#9632;</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#creditsbar {
    width: 100%;
    background color: lightgray;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Muli", Helvetica, Arial;
    padding-left: 20%;
    max-height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
    #creditsbar span {
        word-wrap: normal;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #creditsbar .title {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 80%;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding-right: 5px;

    }
    #creditsbar .name {

    }
    #creditsbar .smallsquare {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _running off the page_?

Comment: The spans don't wrap.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4PqGm/ These show all in one line using your original CSS / HTML. How are you wanting them to look? Wrap how? (remember that spans are inline elements)

Comment: I want the words to fit across the screen, going to multiple lines if they exceed the width of the screen.

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: remove the padding-left: 20%.

Comment: When you say screen do you mean for a monitor? Tablet? Mobile? Are you trying to have a responsive website? The HTML and CSS you provided does not 'exceed the width' of my screen, so they show in one line. If I make my browser smaller, they skip onto two lines.

Comment: @Aravona: On my desktop pc using Chrome, the words run off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `padding-left: 20%;` inside

```
#creditsbar {
width: 100%;
color: #333;
font-family: "Muli", Helvetica, Arial;
padding-left: 20%;
}
```

remove that line and it will work fine

else use  `box-sizing: border-box;` as suggested by @Andy

Comment: Yup, it will also work fine. I have mentioned you in answer :)

Comment: But I want it to have a padding or margin on the left.

Comment: In that case, just add box-sizing: border-box; to the css and it will work. Need not remove padding